# C++/CLI classes and IList

Tags: json, list, c++-cli

I'm trying to deserialize the following JSON using C++/CLI

```
[
    {
        "id":"046e075ad92684",
        "NfcA":{
            "maxTransceiveLength":253,
            "sak":0,
            "atqa":"4400",
            "timeout":618
        },
        "Ndef":[
            {
                "records":[
                    {
                        "id":"",
                        "tnf":1,
                        "type":"54",
                        "payload":"02656e48656c6c6f206d792041737365742049442069733a20303030303031"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "tech":[
            "android.nfc.tech.NfcA",
            "android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight",
            "android.nfc.tech.Ndef"
        ],
        "time":1472468356002
    }
]
```

I have already declared the following classes in order to get the contents of JSON data.

```
ref class tech {
  public: String^ tech1;
  public: String^ tech2;
  public: String^ tech3;
};

ref class Record {
  public: String^ id;
  public: int tnf;
  public: String^ type;
  public: String^ payload;
};

ref class Topic_nfc {
  public: String^ id;
  public: ref class NfcA {
    public: int maxTransceiveLength;
    public: int sak;
    public: int atqa;
    public: int timeout;
  };
  public: ref class Ndef {
    public: System::Collections::Generic::IList<Record^>^ records;
  };
  public: System::Collections::Generic::IList<Ndef^>^ Ndef;
  public: System::Collections::Generic::IList<String^>^ tech;
  public: unsigned long long time;

  public:
    NfcA^ NfcA; 
};
```

After deserialization I can access id and maxTransceiveLength normally using

```
printf("MyRawdata[i]->id : %s\n", MyRawdata[i]->id);
printf("MyRawdata[i]->NfcA->maxTransceiveLength : %d\n", MyRawdata[i]->NfcA->maxTransceiveLength);
```

where `MyRawdata` derived from

```
System::Collections::Generic::IList<Topic_nfc^>^ MyRawdata = JsonConvert::DeserializeObject<System::Collections::Generic::IList<Topic_nfc^>^>(MyJson);
```

However, I can not figure out how we can access `Ndef` and `tech` data members such as `payload`. Can you indicate which is the equivelant for IList ?

Thank you

Comment: Use `List` instead of `IList`, Json.NET doesn't know which concrete class it should use to deserialize to an interface.

Comment: Even using List instead IList, it is not clear to me which is the code to access these data. Which would be the equivelant to `printf("MyRawdata[i]->id : %s\n", MyRawdata[i]->id);` in order to get tech1 data? It 's a little bit confusing to me.

Comment: I don't think that the problem is the `IList`. By setting breakpoints in Visual Studio, I can evaluate the values of `tech1` through the user interface of VS and the values are correct - thus are well set using `JsonConvert`. The question is how I can refer to the MyRawdata structure to access these data with code ?

Comment: Ok then, does `MyRawdata[i]->Ndef[0]->records[0]->payload` return something? I'm not sure what your problem is, really - is it just language syntax? By the way your `tech` class is not used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Lucas! The first thing (language syntax) was an issue, but it is now solved with wht you proposed!
Declaring `public: System::Collections::Generic::List<String^>^ tech;` does not compile and reports `error C2039: 'tech1' : is not a member of 'System::String'`. I tried to change it to `public: System::Collections::Generic::List<**tech**^>^ tech;` but JSon deserializer fails. I can not figure why this list complains about `String`. What am I doing wrong ? I was trying something like that     `printf("MyRawdata[i]->tech[k]->tech1 : %s\n", MyRawdata[i]->tech[k]->tech1);`

Comment: Drop that `->tech1` part, `tech[k]` is a string, that's what the error says

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Lucas Trzesniewski help, I concluded that these lists can be accessed using the following code.

```
for (int k = 0 ; k < MyRawdata[i]->Ndef->Count ; k++) { 
  printf("MyRawdata[i]->Ndef[k]->records[k]->payload : %s\n", MyRawdata[i]->Ndef[k]->records[k]->payload);
}

for (int k = 0 ; k < MyRawdata[i]->tech->Count ; k++) { 
  printf("MyRawdata[i]->tech[k] : %s\n", MyRawdata[i]->tech[k]);
}
```

Actually, it was a matter of syntax to access the data in the respective classes.